# Copying Windows to a new hard drive

Tags: windows-xp, hard-drive, pata, scsi

I have a SCSI drive(C:) with Windows XP on it and I want to copy windows to a partition(F:) on an IDE drive. So far I have used clonezilla to copy Windows from C: to F: and I can boot to F: while the SCSI drive is in the computer, but when I take it out I can't boot to Windows. The IDE drive has Ubuntu on another partition, I'm using GRUB bootloader that has Ubuntu, sda1(Windows C:), and sdb1(not-working windows F:) for options.

The IDE drive obviously needs something from the SCSI drive to boot or is looking in the wrong location, I would like to know what it needs to boot that F: does not have or what it is looking for and the file that specifies where to look.

Comment: Check out this question: http://superuser.com/questions/237866/dual-boot-windows-and-ubuntu-but-with-ubuntu-already-installed-on-a-separate

Answer (score 0):

I presume the error you get when trying to boot to Windows once the SCSI drive has been removed is something like: "Cannot find ntldr". There are a couple of files on the root of the boot drive that windows needs to boot:

```
boot.ini
ntldr
```

Copy these to the root of the Windows partition of the new boot drive.

Also ensure that the entries in the boot.ini point to the correct location:

```
multi(0)disk(0)rdisk(0)partition(1)
```

You may need to change the disk, and/or partition options.